# I ran rails generate devise MODEL before rails generate devise:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I accidentally added my Devise model before running the initial Devise generator.

**Code I ran first:**

```
$ rails generate devise MODEL
```

**Initial Devise generator (what I should have ran first):**

```
$ rails generate devise:install
```

I now have a devise controller called Model that won't let me run 'rake db:migrate'

**Error:**

```
rake aborted!
    User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or  it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside      'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb'
    /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:443:in `raise_no_devise_method_error!'
    /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:211:in `block in devise_for'
    /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
    /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
    /Users/andyHuynh/Code/jargon/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    /Users/andyHuynh/Code/jargon/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Is there a way I can undo this process to run the initial generator first? I am using Rails 3.2.12. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could just delete the generated files and redo again

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can undo generation commands with `rails destroy ...`, so in your case it would be:

```
$ rails destroy devise MODEL
```

If that doesn't work for whatever reason, you can just delete the model and migration - they're only files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The terminal cmd you gave me did not work. Do I need to delete /app/models/models.rb and /db/migrate/23456789_devise_create_models.rb

Comment: Do I need to delete any other files?

Comment: They're the two important files so delete those, but it may have created a test file and fixture file, under the tests directory. Those can be deleted too.

Comment: I deleted the model and migration file. I now get an error: `/Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant User (NameError)`

Comment: There are a few things you can do - it's looking for a class called `User` in app/models, so either try `rails generate devise User` or just create a `User` class manually. Hope that helps

Comment: This command worked for me. @andystructible The reason for the `uninitialized constant User (NameError)` is that you have route `devise_for :users` in your `routes.rb`. If you delete that the problem will be OK.

Answer (score 3):

rails destroy model devise:user
or 
rails destroy scaffold devise:user